# Excel - VBA code to check column A (person's name) against Column H and I, if any of the rows contain "Yes", then add "Yes" to the blank rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

I have an Excel file where Column A contains the name of a person, then some of the Rows under Columns "H" and "I" may contain "yes". What I'm looking for is to add "yes" to all the Rows under Column "H" and "I" if a person has "yes" in any of the Columns "H" and "I". If the person doesn't have a "yes" in any of the columns, then do nothing

Hope that makes sense!

[image]

Desired result would then look like this:

[image]

Comment: How did you try solving the problem by your own? Then, it would be good to see some other cases. Should it be a possibility to have `yes` only in H:H or only in `I:I`? If so, should the solution consider that it does not exist?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tbh I was struggling to know even where to start. To answer your question, if H has a "Yes", then I would have a "Yes" too

Comment: You answer the question after I posted an answer... It checks if both columns (on the same row) have "yes", at least, once. If your data is consistent (always respecting what you try stating above), 'And arr(i, 9) = "yes"` may be excluded. You will gain about a millisecond... :) Please, test the posted answer and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses arrays and a `Dictinary` to keep the names having "yes" in both necessary columns (on the same row) and will be very fast:

```
Sub fillYes()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:I" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array, for faster iteration
  'place the names having yes/yes in a dictionary:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 8) = "yes" And arr(i, 9) = "yes" Then
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = 1
        End If
  Next i
  'place the columns to be adapted in an array:
  arrFin = sh.Range("H2:I" & lastR).Value2
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then arrFin(i, 1) = "yes": arrFin(i, 2) = "yes"
  Next i
  'drop the final array content at once:
  sh.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: @Pan You looked anxious to receive a hint, something and received an answer. Didn't you find some time to test it? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: my apologies for the delay in getting back to you. This worked exactly as requested. I'm immensely grateful for the code you created, and the time you took to investigate this.

Comment: @Pan Glad I could help! I would also like to tell you that we here, when somebody answers our question in a convenient way, vote it up and more important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the supplied solution works...

Comment: I have now done both of those things. I hope this gives you the credit you deserve, as your assistance was excellent, and much appreciated.

Comment: @FanDuru I feel cheeky for asking (please advise if I would need to create a new Question), but would there be much change to the code required to make this work across columns H - L (i.e. 6-11). Please advise if more info is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pan I am afraid, I cannot get you... What "across columns H - L" should mean? And what "i.e. 6-11" should also mean? Are you referring to the columns keeping 'yes'? You should  be clearer when ask something, I think...

Comment: @FanDuru Really appreciate your help, apologies for not explaining better. The code you created previously checked Columns H and I for "Yes" against a person's name. I would like it to check Columns F,G,H,I,J,K (I believe they are called 6-11). Hope that makes sense? Please let me know if further clarification is required. Thanks again.

Comment: What "check" does mean? Now I closed my laptop. I will see your clarefication tomorrow.

Comment: "check" would mean If a User (from Column A) has "Yes" in any row in any of Columns F,G,H,I,J or K, then "Yes" would be auto-populated into every Row for that Column (for that person).

Comment: @Pan OK. Now it is cristal clear. After opening my laptop I will rapidly post an updated code...