# Excel - VBA code to check column A (person's name) against Columns F(6) to K(11), if any contain "Yes", then add "Yes" to the blank rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

@FaneDuru kindly created the code below:

```
Sub fillYes()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:I" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array, for faster iteration
  'place the names having yes/yes in a dictionary:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 8) = "yes" And arr(i, 9) = "yes" Then
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = 1
        End If
  Next i
  'place the columns to be adapted in an array:
  arrFin = sh.Range("H2:I" & lastR).Value2
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then arrFin(i, 1) = "yes": arrFin(i, 2) = "yes"
  Next i
  'drop the final array content at once:
  sh.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Which would check Columns H and I.
I'm just looking to amend this slightly so it also applies to Columns 6,7,8,9,10,11 (F to K).
NOTE - Each column should be treated separately, so for example, if Column F contained a "Yes", that doesn't then automatically mean that all the columns for that person should contain a "Yes"

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012858/excel-vba-code-to-check-column-a-persons-name-against-column-h-and-i-if-an

Comment: I am afraid, I cannot understand what you need. I read carefully your question twice, but I do not know what is to be done. Please, better describe the meaning of: "Each column should be treated separately, so for example, if Column F contained a "Yes", that doesn't then automatically mean that all the columns for that person should contain a "Yes"". You say what **it should NOT contain** and you must explain what is to be done in such a case...

Comment: Hopefully this clarifies, If a User (from Column A) has "Yes" in any row in any of Columns F,G,H,I,J or K, then "Yes" would be auto-populated into every Row for that Column (for that person).

Comment: Yes, this last statement clarifies the issue. I will place an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next adapted answer. To avoid an imbricated range of many `If - End If` statements, I created `boolYes` variable which will become `True` of the first "yes" occurrence in the mentioned columns. The code also is able to deal with "Yes" or "YES" instead of only "yes":

```
Sub fillYes_Extended()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
  Dim j As Long, boolYes As Boolean
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:K" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array, for faster iteration
  
  'place the names having yes/yes in the required columns, in a dictionary:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 6 To 11
            If LCase(arr(i, j)) = "yes" Then boolYes = True: Exit For
        Next j
        If boolYes Then
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = 1: boolYes = False 'add the dictionary key and reinitialize boolYes variable
        End If
  Next i
  'place the columns to be adapted in an array:
  arrFin = sh.Range("F2:K" & lastR).Value2
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            For j = 1 To 6
                arrFin(i, j) = "yes"
            Next j
        End If
  Next i

  'drop the final array content at once:
  sh.Range("F2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.